# Jquery syntax error only in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, internet-explorer-11

I have a main page that load another html page with some javascript inside.
Unfortunately, in IE 11 the debugger retrieve me a syntax error in jquery.2.1.0.min.js. The javascript isn't executed at all.
With all other browsers the problem doesn't exist. I've checked the script with javascript lint, but there aren't significant error.

If you want the online test:
[TwisteggUp](http://www.twisteggup.com), than click on "What" menu and than click on "Web" span.

```
 //dichiarazioni globali
var servUrl;
var $currGallery;
var currPortrait;
var currTabIndex;
//switch iniziale
if ($('#pageType').attr('value') == 'web') {
    servUrl = "/EggWS.asmx/GetWebProjects";
}
else {
    servUrl = "/EggWS.asmx/GetGraphicProjects";
}
//richiesta Ajax
SwitchAjaxBrowser(servUrl);
//funzioni per richieste Ajax
function SwitchAjaxBrowser(servUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: servUrl,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) { ProcessAjaxRequest(xml); },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
        }
    });
}
function ProcessAjaxRequest(xml) {
    //crea oggetti progetto
    console.log(xml);
    var i = 0;
    var pjCount = $(xml).find('Project').length;
    $(xml).find('Project').each(function () {
        var pjObject = $('#pj' + i);
        console.log($(this).find('Name').text());
        pjObject.children('.pjContent').children('.pjName').html($(this).find('Name').text());
        pjObject.children('.pjContent').children('.pjDesc').load($(this).find('Description').text());
        pjObject.children('.pjContent').children('.pjFullDesc').html($(this).find('FullDescription').text());
        pjObject.children('.pjContent').children('.pjSkills').html($(this).find('Skills').text());
        //popolo le info e la galleria nascosta
        pjObject.children('.pjContent').children('.pjmImage').attr('src', $(this).find('MainImage').text());
        //archivio i dati con le info delle immagini
        $(this).find('ProjectImage').each(function () {
            pjObject.children('.pjContent').children('.pjmImage').clone(false).attr('src', $(this).text()).removeClass('pjmImage').addClass('pjmDetailImageGallery').appendTo(pjObject.children('.pjContent').children('.pjGallery'));
        });
        //se è il terzo oggetto
        if ((i > 0) && ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) && (i < (pjCount - 1))) {
            pjObject.parent().clone().empty().insertAfter(pjObject.parent());
            $('.pjPager').last().data('index', (i + 1) / 3);
            pjObject.clone().attr('id', 'pj' + (i + 1)).appendTo($('.pjPager').last()).children('.pjContent').children('.pjGallery').html('');
        } else
            //se non è l'ultimo, clona l'oggetto
            if (i < (pjCount - 1)) {
                pjObject.clone().attr('id', 'pj' + (i + 1)).insertAfter(pjObject).children('.pjContent').children('.pjGallery').html('');
            }
        i++;
    });
    $('.pjLoad').fadeOut(500);
    $('#pjGeneralContainer').children('.pjPager').fadeIn(500);
    //correla l'evento di caricamento generale alla visualizzazione.
    //$('#pjGeneralContainer').waitForImages(function () {

    //});
    //gestione dell'hovering per tutti i progetti
    $('.pjContent').each(function () {
        $(this).children('.pjDesc').mouseover(function (e) {
            $(this).stop().animate({ height: '365px' }, { duration: 600, step: function (now) { $(this).css('height', now + 'px'); } });
        });
    });
    $('.pjContent').each(function () {
        $(this).children('.pjDesc').mouseout(function (e) {
            $(this).stop().animate({ height: '30px' }, { duration: 600, step: function (now) { $(this).css('height', now + 'px'); } });
        });
    });
    //popolamento scheda singolo progetto
    $('.pjContent').on('click', function () {
        PopulateDetailedContainer($(this));
    });
    $('.pjBtn').on('click', function () { moveGallery($(this)); });
    //scomparsa dettaglio progetto
    function CancelDetailedContainer() {
        $('#pjDetailContainer').fadeOut(500);
        $('#pjGeneralContainer').fadeIn(500);
        $('.pjNav').fadeIn(500);
        //svuoto le informazioni
        $('.pjDetailmImage').attr('src', '');
        $('.pjDetailTitle').html('');
        $('.pjDetailFullDesc').html('');
        $('.pjTab3Skill').html('');
        $('.pjDetailGallery').html('');
        //ripristino le condizioni iniziali
        $('.pjDetailTab2').css('height', '100px');
        $('.pjDetailTab3').css('height', '100px');
        $('.pjBtn').removeClass('pjBtnDown');
        $('.pjBtn').removeClass('pjBtnUp');
        $('.pjBtn').addClass('pjBtnUp');
    }
    function PopulateDetailedContainer($projectContent) {
        $currGallery = $projectContent.children('.pjGallery');
        currTabIndex = 0;
        //effetti di transizione
        $('#pjGeneralContainer').fadeOut(500);
        $('.pjNav').fadeOut(500);
        $('#pjDetailContainer').fadeIn(500);
        //popolo le informazioni
        $('.pjDetailmImage').attr('src', $projectContent.children('.pjmImage').attr('src'));
        var cancBtn = "<a class='btnDetailCancel' />";
        $('.pjDetailTitle').html(cancBtn + $projectContent.children('.pjName').html());
        $('.pjDetailTitle').children('.btnDetailCancel').on('click', function () { CancelDetailedContainer(); });
        $('.pjDetailFullDesc').load($projectContent.children('.pjFullDesc').html());
        $('.pjTab3Skill').load($projectContent.children('.pjSkills').html());
        var sliderBtn = "<a class='sliderLeft'/><a class='sliderRight'/>";
        $('.pjDetailGallery').html($projectContent.children('.pjGallery').html());
        //controllo orientamento per galleria - inizializzazione owl
        buildGallery();
        $(window).resize(function () { moveGallery(null); });
    }
    function assignGalleryHeight() {
        var wHeight = $('.SiteBody').height();
        var galleryHeight = wHeight - 350;
        var galleryWidth = $('.pjDetailGallery').width();
        switch (currTabIndex) {
            case 0:
                $('.pjDetailTab2').css('height', '100px');
                $('.pjDetailTab3').css('height', '100px');
                break;
            case 1:
                $('.pjDetailTab2').css('height', (wHeight - 250) + 'px');
                $('.pjDetailTab3').css('height', '100px');
                break;
            case 2:
                $('.pjDetailTab2').css('height', (wHeight - 250) + 'px');
                $('.pjDetailTab3').css('height', (wHeight - 250) + 'px');
                break;
        }
        $('.pjmDetailImageGallery').removeAttr('style');
        //se orizzontale una sola immagine, se verticale 2 immagini
        if (localStorage['portrait'] == 'Y') {
            $('.pjmDetailImageGallery').css('max-height', (galleryHeight - 30) + 'px');
            $('.pjmDetailImageGallery').css('max-width', (galleryWidth) + 'px');
            $('.pjmDetailImageGallery').css('margin-top', '0px');
            //eliminazione visualizzazione speciale
            $('.pjDetailmImage').removeAttr('style');
            $('.pjDetailTab1').removeAttr('style');
            $('.pjDetailFullDesc').removeAttr('style');
        }
        else {
            $('.pjmDetailImageGallery').css('max-height', (galleryHeight - 50) / 2 + 'px');
            $('.pjmDetailImageGallery').css('max-width', (galleryWidth) + 'px');
            $('.pjmDetailImageGallery').css('margin-top', '10px');
            //visualizzazione speciale
            $('.pjDetailmImage').css('float', 'none');
            $('.pjDetailmImage').css('height', '600px');
            $('.pjDetailmImage').css('margin-top', '30px');
            $('.pjDetailTab1').css('text-align', 'center');
            $('.pjDetailTab1').css('text-align', 'center');
            $('.pjDetailFullDesc').css('font-size', '150%');
        }
    }
    function buildGallery() {
        //azzeramento di sicurezza delle informazioni
        var $pjDetailGallery = $('.pjDetailGallery');
        $pjDetailGallery.html("");
        if (typeof $pjDetailGallery.data('owlCarousel') != 'undefined') {
            $pjDetailGallery.data('owlCarousel').destroy();
            $pjDetailGallery.removeClass('owl-carousel');
        }
        //resetto i bottoni
        currTabIndex = 0;
        $('.pjTab2Title').children('div').removeClass('pjBtnDown');
        if (!$('.pjTab2Title').children('div').hasClass('pjBtnUp'))
            $('.pjTab2Title').children('div').addClass('pjBtnUp');
        $('.pjTab3Title').children('div').removeClass('pjBtnDown');
        if (!$('.pjTab3Title').children('div').hasClass('pjBtnUp'))
            $('.pjTab3Title').children('div').addClass('pjBtnUp');
        //recupero le info della galleria
        if (localStorage['portrait'] == 'Y') {
            //ricreo gli oggetti come erano
            $('.pjDetailGallery').html($currGallery.html());
        }
        else {
            //ricreo gli oggetti a coppie
            k = 0;
            $currGallery.children().each(function () {
                if (k % 2 == 0) {
                    $pjDetailGallery.append("<div class='verticalGallery'></div>");
                }
                $(this).clone().appendTo($pjDetailGallery.children('div').last());
                k++;
            });
        }
        assignGalleryHeight();
        if (localStorage['portrait'] == 'Y') {
            $pjDetailGallery.owlCarousel({
                items: 1,
                itemsCustom: [0, 1],
                scrollPerPage: true
            });
        }
        else {
            $pjDetailGallery.owlCarousel({
                items: 1,
                itemsCustom: [0, 1],
                scrollPerPage: true
            });
        }
    }
    //gestione movimento tra schede del progetto singolo
    function moveGallery($btn) {
        var wHeight = $('.SiteBody').height();
        //per il resize della finestra
        if ($btn == null) {
            //se è cambiato l'orientamento della pagina ricostruisco tutto
            if (currPortrait != localStorage['portrait']) {
                buildGallery();
                currPortrait = localStorage['portrait'];
                return;
            }
            assignGalleryHeight();
            return;
        }
        //la finestra deve salire
        if ($btn.hasClass('pjBtnUp')) {
            $('.pjDetailGallery').css('height', (wHeight - 350) + 'px');
            switch ($btn.data('index')) {
                case 1:
                    $('.pjDetailTab2').stop().animate({ height: (wHeight - 250) + 'px' }, { duration: 600, step: function (now) { $(this).css('height', now + 'px'); } });
                    $btn.removeClass('pjBtnUp');
                    $btn.addClass('pjBtnDown');
                    currTabIndex = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $('.pjDetailTab2').stop().animate({ height: (wHeight - 250) + 'px' }, { duration: 600, step: function (now) { $(this).css('height', now + 'px'); } });
                    $('.pjDetailTab3').stop().animate({ height: (wHeight - 250) + 'px' }, { duration: 600, step: function (now) { $(this).css('height', now + 'px'); } });
                    $btn.removeClass('pjBtnUp');
                    $btn.addClass('pjBtnDown');
                    $('.pjTab2Title').children('div').removeClass('pjBtnUp');
                    if (!$('.pjTab2Title').children('div').hasClass('pjBtnDown'))
                        $('.pjTab2Title').children('div').addClass('pjBtnDown');
                    currTabIndex = 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
            //la finestra deve scendere
        else {
            switch ($btn.data('index')) {
                case 1:
                    $('.pjDetailTab2').stop().animate({ height: '100px' }, { duration: 600, step: function (now) { $(this).css('height', now + 'px'); } });
                    $('.pjDetailTab3').stop().animate({ height: '100px' }, { duration: 600, step: function (now) { $(this).css('height', now + 'px'); } });
                    $btn.removeClass('pjBtnDown');
                    $btn.addClass('pjBtnUp');
                    $('.pjTab3Title').children('div').removeClass('pjBtnDown');
                    if (!$('.pjTab3Title').children('div').hasClass('pjBtnUp'))
                        $('.pjTab3Title').children('div').addClass('pjBtnUp');
                    currTabIndex = 0;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $('.pjDetailTab3').stop().animate({ height: '100px' }, { duration: 600, step: function (now) { $(this).css('height', now + 'px'); } });
                    $btn.removeClass('pjBtnDown');
                    $btn.addClass('pjBtnUp');
                    currTabIndex = 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        //checkGalleryPortrait();
    }
    //termine controllo caricamento portfolio
    localStorage['folioisloading'] = 'N';
    //Inizializzazione transizioni
    InitiateTransition();
    return false;
}
function InitiateTransition() {
    var $main = $('#pjGeneralContainer'),
        $pages = $main.children('div.pt-page'),
        animcursor = 1,
        pagesCount = $pages.length,
        current = 0,
        isAnimating = false,
        endCurrPage = false,
        endNextPage = false,
        animEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitAnimation': 'webkitAnimationEnd',
            'OAnimation': 'oAnimationEnd',
            'msAnimation': 'MSAnimationEnd',
            'animation': 'animationend'
        },
        // animation end event name
        animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('animation')],
        // support css animations
        support = Modernizr.cssanimations;

    function init() {

        $pages.each(function () {
            var $page = $(this);
            $page.data('originalClassList', $page.attr('class'));
        });

        $pages.eq(current).addClass('pt-page-current');
        CreateNav();
        responsive();
    }
    function CreateNav() {
        var i = 0;
        //navigazione precedente
        $('.pjNav').append("<a class='pjNavPrev pjNavIcon' />");
        $('.pjNav').children().last().on('click', function () {
            previousPager();
        });
        //navigazione checkbox
        $main.children('.pjPager').each(function () {
            var $pjPager = $(this);
            $('.pjNav').append("<a class='pjNavButton' data-index='" + $pjPager.data('index') + "' />");
            if (i == 0)
                $('.pjNav').children().last().css('margin-left', '0px');
            $('.pjNav').children().last().on('click', function () {
                goToPager($pjPager.data('index'));
            });
            i++;
        });
        //navigazione successivo
        $('.pjNav').append("<a class='pjNavNext pjNavIcon' />");
        $('.pjNav').children().last().on('click', function () {
            nextPager();
        });
        $('.pjNavButton').each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('index') == 0)
                $(this).addClass('pjNavButtonCurrent');
            else
                $(this).removeClass('pjNavButtonCurrent');
        });
    }
    //funzioni di navigazione
    function goToPager(toPageIndex) {
        if (current == toPageIndex)
            return false;
        if (isAnimating)
            return false;

        isAnimating = true;
        var $currPage = $pages.eq(current);
        var $nextPage = $pages.eq(toPageIndex).addClass('pt-page-current');

        //seleziono il bottone di navigazione corrente
        $('.pjNavButton').each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('index') == toPageIndex)
                $(this).addClass('pjNavButtonCurrent');
            else
                $(this).removeClass('pjNavButtonCurrent');
        });
        //imposto lo stile dell'animazione
        if (current > toPageIndex) {
            outClass = 'pt-page-rotatePushRight';
            inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromLeft';
        }
        else {
            outClass = 'pt-page-rotatePushLeft';
            inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromRight';
        }


        current = toPageIndex;

        $currPage.addClass(outClass).on(animEndEventName, function () {
            $currPage.off(animEndEventName);
            endCurrPage = true;
            if (endNextPage) {
                onEndAnimation($currPage, $nextPage);
            }
        });

        $nextPage.addClass(inClass).on(animEndEventName, function () {
            $nextPage.off(animEndEventName);
            endNextPage = true;
            if (endCurrPage) {
                onEndAnimation($currPage, $nextPage);
            }
        });

        if (!support) {
            onEndAnimation($currPage, $nextPage);
        }

    }
    function nextPager() {

        if (current < pagesCount - 1) {
            goToPager(current + 1);
        }

    }
    function previousPager() {

        if (current > 0) {
            goToPager(current - 1);
        }

    }
    function onEndAnimation($outpage, $inpage) {
        endCurrPage = false;
        endNextPage = false;
        resetPage($outpage, $inpage);
        isAnimating = false;
        //animazione di transizione completata.-> da inserire qui animazione dei progetti (se la facciamo).
    }
    function resetPage($outpage, $inpage) {
        $outpage.attr('class', $outpage.data('originalClassList'));
        $inpage.attr('class', $inpage.data('originalClassList') + ' pt-page-current');
    }
    //funzione per lo scroll
    function responsive() {

        $(document).bind("swipeRight", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            nextPager();
        }).bind("swipeLeft", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            previousPager();
        });

        $(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var delta = event.originalEvent.deltaX;
            init_scroll(event, delta);
        });
    }
    //funzione accessoria per lo scroll
    function init_scroll(event, delta) {
        // Cancel scroll if currently animating or within quiet period
        if (isAnimating) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        if (delta < 0) {
            nextPager();
        } else {
            if (delta > 0) {
                previousPager();
            }
        }
    }
    //mappatura con le freccie su/giù
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        switch (e.which) {
            case 37:
                if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') previousPager();
                break;
            case 39:
                if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') nextPager();
                break;
            default: return;
        }
    });
    //gestione dei tab singolo progetto
    init();
    return { init: init };

}
```

Comment: SCRIPT1002: Sintax error. But I can't understand why it's only in IE.

Comment: On which line, which column?

Comment: This site can’t be reached - www.twisteggup.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved!
I don't know why, but for IE the piece of code:

```
   $(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') previousPager();
            break;
        case 39:
            if (tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea') nextPager();
            break;
        default: return;
    }
});
```

Inside the internal script causes syntax error.
I have the same code in the main page with other (e.which) and there it works. Such a mistery!